# Configurar orphanRemoval=true em Generate Entities of Table - JPA Tools - Eclipse

Tags: java, jpa, eclipse

Estou tendo problema toda vez que preciso usar o Generate Entities of Table do JPA Tools (uso Eclipse Neon.3). Eu gero as entidades com o comando Generate Entities of Table do JPA Tools. No código de uma classe na anotação de um relacionamento adiciono  o codigo `orphanRemoval=true` e salvo tudo certo. Quando preciso usar novamente o comando Generate Entities of Table, quando vou olhar a mesma classe que inseri o `orphanRemoval=true` já não existe mais.

**Como faço para configurar o JPATools (nas telas de Generate Custom Entities) para inserir o orphanRemoval=true num relacionamento, de modo que esta fique memorizada e toda vez que precisar usar o comando de gerar as entidades de tabelas ele automaticamente insira o orphanRemoval?** Assim como vc seleciona cascade na tela Generate Custom Entities e ele mantem memorizada.

Veja o trecho de código do caso abaixo:

Quando gero a entidade com o JPA Tools:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoa", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<PessoaContato> listaPessoaContato;
```

Insiro manualmente no codigo o orphanRemoval e salvo:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoa", cascade={CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<PessoaContato> listaPessoaContato;
```

Quando preciso regerar novamente, o jpa tools sobreescreve todas as classes apagando tudo que é inserido manualmente, dessa forma o trecho de código volta a ficar:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoa", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<PessoaContato> listaPessoaContato;
```

Comment: Olá, FredeBr. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Infelizmente eu não sei responder à pergunta (até porque faz anos que não uso mais o Eclipse). No entanto, quero avisar aos que votaram para fechar que a pergunta é perfeitamente clara: o autor da pergunta está usando uma ferramenta de geração de código no editor Eclipse e precisa que o código gerado tenha uma certa característica. Se é ou não possível customizar a ferramenta eu não sei, mas é uma pergunta perfeitamente válida.

Answer (score 1):

A única [referência direta sobre tal opção](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/200522/) que encontrei é de muitos anos atrás e basicamente foi dito que não era suportada e não havia planos para isto.

O motivo, creio, é porque a ferramenta de geração de entidades baseadas em tabelas é uma ajuda inicial e não tem pretensão de automatizar a evolução das classes através da regeneração das mesmas em cada mudança do banco.

Fiz uma pesquisa para ver se havia uma forma de ligar tal opção por padrão ou sobrescrever a anotação externamente, independente da anotação do campo, mas não encontrei nenhum resultado.

A melhor solução seria usar a ferramenta apenas para gerar apenas as classes referentes às novas tabelas, sem sobrescrever as existentes.

Uma alternativa seria criar uma ferramenta para processar as classes geradas e adicionar a informação onde for conveniente de forma automática.

Comment: Realmente, o JPA Tools infelizmente não tem esta opção e já tinha visto esta referência que você citou. Achei interessante que nas telas de Generate Custom Entities ele dá opções de você definir o tipo de cascade, o fetch e memoriza esta informações pois se você regerar as entidades nestas telas serão mostradas as configurações que vc definiu anteriormente. Optei pela inserção manual mesmo através do JPA Diagram Editor. Vamos ver se no futuro o pessoal do projeto resolva implementar. Obrigado pelo retorno.